# Backup gets stuck at /proc/kcore ,what to do?

Tags: backup, tar

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit
Trying to back up a system using this command:

```
tar -cvpzf /backup.tgz –exclude=/proc –exclude=/lost+found –exclude=/backup.tgz –exclude=/mnt –exclude=/sys /
```

As you can see */proc* is excluded, but system still tries to back it up and always fails. I tried to make it more specific:

```
tar -cvpzf /backup.tgz –exclude=/var/lib/named/proc –exclude=/lost+found –exclude=/backup.tgz –exclude=/mnt –exclude=/sys
```

Didn't help either. What should I do? I found many people have this problem, yet, didn't find a single good explanation on how to fix it when backing up a system. I'm a noob, so, be specific. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Nameless Narrator: please do not use `<` and `>` to *highlight* your commands. They are treated as HTML tags then and won't be displayed. Use the formatting of this site provides. Please also doublecheck your commands. It also should be `--exclude` (double hyphen, not single).

Comment: Maybe the single hyphen was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the comments above has the answer, which is using --exclude with double hyphen. I would like to note that copy pasting from the question results in ? marks in my console thus the dash stripes might be changed inadvertently (maybe by a word processing software) into EN dash unicode character. Changing the EN dash into two character ANSI dash does the trick.

But in my system running similar tar command stuck on  /var/lib/ntp/proc/kcore file, which were mounted by ntp. In such cases do check mounted proc locations and other non-filesystem mounts and then add exclude clauses accordingly :

```
rtremsapp01:~ # mount
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root on / type ext3 (rw,acl,user_xattr)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=1777,size=71g)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,mode=0620,gid=5)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw,acl,user_xattr)
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_var on /var type ext3 (rw,acl,user_xattr)
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_master on /master type ext3 (rw,acl,user_xattr)
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_usrsap on /usr/sap/RP0 type ext3 (rw,acl,user_xattr)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
none on /var/lib/ntp/proc type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev)
rtremsapp01:~ # tar -cvpzf /backup/backuprtremsapp01.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude /backup --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys / --exclude=/var/lib/ntp/proc  --exclude=/dev --exclude=/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
```

Having multiple filesystem mounts, it might be beneficial to backup each mount point separately using --one-file-system option though..

```
rtremsapp01:~ # tar --one-file-system -czf /backup/rtremsapp/var.tar.gz /var & 
rtremsapp01:~ # tar --one-file-system -czf /backup/rtremsapp/root.tar.gz /  & 
rtremsapp01:~ # tar --one-file-system -czf /backup/rtremsapp/master.tar.gz /master  &
rtremsapp01:~ # tar --one-file-system -czf /backup/rtremsapp/boot.tar.gz /boot  & 
rtremsapp01:~ # tar --one-file-system -czf /backup/rtremsapp/usr_sap_RP0.tar.gz /usr/sap/RP0  &
```